# How do I get the default color palette back in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

So for some reason, totally unknown to me, I now have a very annoying color picker setup in Photoshop.  At the moment, whenever I change the colour in the right-hand color selector (which updates the main selector area) the colors available in that right hand area totally change.  Very annoying, and very difficult to get a color you want.  See screenshot below of my current color picker:

> *(attempted image post. However, image is behind an Amazon S3 user log in and will not show here.)*

The default one worked very well for me, and I want it back.  How?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the 'H' radio button fixes it, previously it was set to 'R' which is selecting from the 'Red' spectrum, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose Adobe's color picker from Photoshop's preferences window.

[image: Photoshop Preferences Window]